# How to send Discord Webhook when machine is started or shutdowned?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shutdown

I wrote a bash script that would send Discord Webhook message.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
WEBHOOK_URL="https://discord.com/api/webhooks/[REDACTED]"
curl -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  -d '{"content": ":stop_button: Server machine has been shutdowned."}' \
  ${WEBHOOK_URL}
sleep 3
```

and I put this script as `/etc/rc0.d/S90server_shutdown.sh`. (PS. you can ignore `sleep 3` because it doesn't matter if it exists or not)

The problem is, when I tested this script in Git Bash, it works. It sends Webhook message correctly. But when I applied this script to real machine, it doesn't send Webhook messages.

I wrote another script that enables WOL at shutdown and put it together(as `/etc/rc0.d/S92wol_shutdown.sh`) with Webhook script. WOL script works, but Webhook script doesn't work.

What could be a reason of this?

Comment: Are you sure that the network is still up at that point in the shutdown?

Comment: @user535733 I don't sure for default files like 'K01open-iscsi' kills network stuff, but 'S92wol_shutdown.sh' will 'down' network via 'ifconfig [name] down' command. And since Webhook script will run prior to that 'S92wol_shutdown.sh' because it has name as 'S90~~' so it will be executed first. I even put 'sleep' command to that file tying to give script sufficient time to send Webhook message but no success.

Comment: Test it: Run a S90~~ job that outputs your network settings and a test ping to a file. Then you will know.

Comment: @user535733 'S90server_shutdown.sh' won't touch network settings. Only 'S92wol_poweroff.sh' will touch network settings with 'ifconfig down' command if no other default startup/shutdown script touches it. And It works very well. I even inserted 'wait $!' just below 'curl' command but no success.